# Changing from cartesian to polar

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, coordinate-transformation

I want to change the following integral to the polar form $$\int_{y=0}^a \int_y^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}(x^2+y^2) dx dy,\ a>0$$ in Mathematica.I would be highly obliged for any help

Comment: "Use `IntegrateChangeVariables`! " <- Sadly this isn't an answer to your question. (Your example is an extension of 3rd example of `IntegrateChangeVariables`, though. Do you intentionally ask this after reading the document of `IntegrateChangeVariables`?) BTW, I think the integral can be transformed to polar coordinates only if $-1\leq a\leq1$?

Answer (score 5):

- The formula is wrong.  `Sqrt[1 - y^2]` should be `Sqrt[a^2 - y^2]`
  Mathematica can handle such integration directly.

```
Clear[reg];
reg = ImplicitRegion[{0 <= y <= a, y <= x <= Sqrt[a^2 - y^2]}, {x, y}];
Integrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, y} ∈ reg, Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

[image]

- For the corrected integral, we can also use `IntegrateChangeVariables`.

```
intCartesian = 
 Inactive[Integrate][x^2 + y^2, {y, 0, a}, {x, y, Sqrt[a^2 - y^2]}]
intPolar = 
 IntegrateChangeVariables[intCartesian, {r, θ}, 
  "Cartesian" -> "Polar"]
Activate[intPolar]
```

[image]

### Appendix

When `a` is less equal to `1/Sqrt[2]`, for example `a=1/2`, the questioner's region
is

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{0 <= y <= 1/2, y <= x <= Sqrt[1 - y^2]}, {x, y}];
% // Region
```

[image]

It is not a regular sector,so it it hardly to use polar coordinate to calculate such integration(but cartesian coordinate work),that is why the `IntegrateChangeVariables` cann't work for this case.

Comment: What if the formula is not wrong and OP just want to study that integral :) ?

Comment: By the way : Mathematica is able to solve the "wrong" integral analytically.

Comment: @xzczd   It seems that `IntegrateChangeVariables` not easy to do with the parametric `a`.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, I have test the wrong integral, for example ,when `a=1/2`, it is impossible calculate the integral by change the variable using polar coordinate since the region in not a regular sector.

Comment: @cvgmt I tried (Mathematica v12.2) `Integrate[(x^2 + y^2), {y, 0, a}, {x, y, Sqrt[1 - y^2]}]` which evaluates to `1/12 (a Sqrt[1 - a^2] + 2 a^3 (-2 a + Sqrt[1 - a^2]) + 3 ArcSin[a]) for -1<a<1`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  I means that it is impossible by polar integration as OP mention,but it actual can by cartesian integration!

Comment: @cvgmt It isn't impossible to use polar coordinates, integration range has to be splitted

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, the wrong integration is easy split in cartesian coordinate,but not easy  in polar coordinate.